# Possible to search/replace in awk before columns are parsed?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

In my script below I assume that the input file always has a space before and after `:`, however it isn't always the case that the input file have this.

```
awk '!/^#/ && !/000000000000/ && /[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}/ {
    print "host "$5" {"

    gsub(/..\B/,"&:", $3)
    print "  hardware ethernet "$3";"

    print "  fixed-address "$1";"
    print "}"
    print ""
}' hosts > reservations.conf
```

**Question**

Is it possible to do a global search and replace for `":"` with `" : "` (there is a space before and after the `":"`) before awk begins to parse the file? It should be done in memory, so the input file isn't changed on disk.

I guess it could be done with `sed` and then pipe it to awk afterwards, but it is often I run into this kind of situation, so I'd really like to know if there is a way to do it within awk or gawk.

**Example of input data**

```
10.52.0.1 : 000000000000 : newhost-52-1  : # 
10.52.0.2 : 180373D0FE86:  ster.dtocal :#
```

**Example of wanted output**

```
host newhost-52-1 {
  hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
  fixed-address 10.52.0.1;
}

host ster.dtocal {
  hardware ethernet 18:03:73:D0:FE:86;
  fixed-address 10.52.0.2;
}
```

Comment: Could you please mention expected output too here once?

Comment: _I assume that the input file always have a space before and after `:`_ where and how in the code do you assume it?

Comment: @JamesBrown because I separate by spaces, and `:` should never be part of a string.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Now added =)

Comment: @SandraSchlichting, could you please mention how mac address is coming in your output? I can't see that in your input, please explain.

Comment: Are you using GNU awk?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting please correct either your input sample or output sample so that they match based on the script you have provided.. regarding the question, I think you should use `split` function to get an array with field values instead of using `$1`, `$2`, etc

Comment: @JamesBrown. Yes, I use gawk.

Comment: @Sundeep ups. sorry. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you seem to be relying on the default FS. If you are using GNU awk define it `awk -F" *: *" ...`:

```
$ awk -F" *: *" '
!/^#/ && !/000000000000/ && /[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}/ {
    print "host "$3" {"

    gsub(/..\B/,"&:", $2)
    print "  hardware ethernet "$2";"

    print "  fixed-address "$1";"
    print "}"
    print ""
}' file
host ster.dtocal {
  hardware ethernet 18:03:73:D0:FE:86;
  fixed-address 10.52.0.2;
}
```

I changed the `$n`s in your code to more appropriate but as the input and output samples did not match I didn't spend too much time on wondering what the output should look like.

Comment: You probably get the other host entry in the output if you remove that `&& !/000000000000/` in your code which I blindly cut and pasted.

Comment: as far as I know, multicharacter FS is POSIX and gawk is not necessarily needed here ;)

Comment: Well, it didn't work with mawk or awk-20121220 in Linux but it did work with GNU awk and busybox awk. That's all I had time for (and versions at hand). _Are you on busybox awk_ would've been weird :D.

Answer (score 1):

On a side note: your original question was *Possible to search/replace in awk before columns are parsed?*. The answer to this question is yes, it is possible.

When you redefine the variable `$0` awk will essentially redefine all fields and the corresponding variable `NF`. So essentially you could do something like this:

```
awk '{gsub(/foo/,"foo bar")}{...}'
```

Or

```
awk '{$0=$0" "new_field"}{...}'
```

In the first case, `$0` is redefined directly in the `gsub` command, in the second case it is redefined by assignment. Example:

```
$ echo "1 2 3" | awk '{sub("3","3 4")}{print NF"|" $1,$2,$3,$4}'
4|1 2 3 4
$ echo "1 2 3" | awk '{$0=$0" foo"}{print NF"|" $1,$2,$3,$4}'
4|1 2 3 foo
```